# How to change Map.key to String in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

First I've defined

module StringMap = Map.Make(String);;

and I have a list generated by StringMap.bindings, the types in the list are (StringMap.key × int).I want to use the key as a string so that I can compare them, how could I change its the type of the list?

Answer (score 3):

Your type `StringMap.key` is a synonym for `string`. There is no need to convert, they are the same type.

```
# let mymap = StringMap.singleton "abc" 14;;
val mymap : int StringMap.t = <abstr>
# StringMap.bindings mymap;;
- : (StringMap.key * int) list = [("abc", 14)]
# fst (List.hd (StringMap.bindings mymap)) = "abc";;
- : bool = true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I've found another bug which causes an error in my code. I've thought the error is caused by type mismatch.

Comment: If there is a type mismatch, the compiler will specifically tell you about it. The point of a strongly type language is that type errors can always be detected. If the compiler doesn't mention any type mismatches specifically, then your problem is something else.